# Why does Java ProcessBuilder log a RuntimeException stackTrace when no error actually happened?

Tags: java, logging

We use the Java stdlib `java.lang.ProcessBuilder` class to run a process.

When DEBUG logging is enabled, we see the following message being logged even when there's no errors:

```
DEBUG main java.lang.ProcessBuilder - ProcessBuilder.start(): pid: 297, dir: /opt/user/var/, cmd: "/bin/mycommand"
java.lang.RuntimeException: ProcessBuilder.start() debug
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
```

Looking at the ProcessBuilder source code, we found that this is just normal behaviour, not some actual error:

```java
RuntimeException stackTraceEx = new RuntimeException("ProcessBuilder.start() debug");
LOGGER.log(level, "ProcessBuilder.start(): pid: " + process.pid() +
                        ", dir: " + dir +
                        ", cmd: \"" + cmdargs + "\"",
                        stackTraceEx);
```

This looks very weird: why would a Java stdlib class want to log the stackTrace of a call simply for debugging purposes?

EDIT: this seems to have been introduced in Java 21... Java 17 [doesn't do this](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u-dev/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.java).

Comment: Why it is logged? exactly because "*DEBUG logging is enabled*" (actually you must ask the developers of `ProcessBuilder`, I can only guess that they thought it would be helpful for debugging; maybe to show where (when) it is being called from)

Comment: It is menttioned in JDK21 [release notes](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/21all-relnotes.html) and [JDK8303392](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8303392). Seems odd not to be trace level though.

Comment: Because they wanted to log it.

Comment: The message only tells you that a process was started. The stack trace tells you _which code_ started the process.

Comment: Because they wanted to help you debug possible problems (for example: the process that you are trying to start doesn't start because you are trying to start it in the wrong directory or use the wrong command to start).

Comment: As far as I know, there's no other place where the Java stdlib logs a stacktrace for a **successful** method call. This is not something I expect any programming language's standard library to be doing and it's honestly bizarre that they think it's ok to do that.

Comment: Evidently the JDK developers believe spawning a process deserves more debugging information than just a message. Personally, I don't find logging a stack trace at a non-error level particularly bizarre in and of itself. Though if I were implementing this, I would only include the stack trace at the "trace" level.